# Is there a way to find setter method by its getter method or vice versa in a class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, getter-setter

Sometimes related getter and setter methods are not near or under each other in massive classes and finding a setter using its corresponding getter method isn't handy. I know I can select the rest of the method name except the get or set letters from the beginning and hit the `Ctrl+F3`. Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use **Structure** (Alt+7) panel with active features "*Show properties*" (**P** icon), "*Autoscroll from source*" and "*Autoscroll to source*".
If you on setter, getter or field and pressed Alt+7, you will be placed on the parameter and then could be easily switch between them with arrows up and down.[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do that by

   `copy property name` (Ctrl + C) + `Ctrl+F3` + Paste (Ctrl + V)

As showing in screen shoot bellow:

[image: Select getter setter]

You can type anything to search when press `Ctrl+F3`

2. Additional for clean code, you should refactor it by putting getter and setter near each other. 
   NOTE: there is an IDE code style rule to help with this: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Arrangement | **Keep getters and setters together**

Comment: I know this approach, I want a way easier than this.